# How does CloudFlare work with webapps?

Tags: cloudflare

I have an app that needs to constantly ping an HTTP server, so that I can see if my app is running.

I want to run my server  through CloudFlare. Will every request query my server (if it's up)?

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you're asking if pings to your site through CloudFlare's network will be returned by your server? Not if your site is being proxied (i.e., has an orange cloud to indicate that proxy is active on it). In that case, you'll be pinging CloudFlare's server that your host resolves to (the IP listed in your DNS record) - see [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169216-Why-do-I-see-CloudFlare-s-IPs-when-I-do-a-ping-or-traceroute-to-my-site-).

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here. If you are caching the entire application through cloudflare then you will need to ping the actual server address (in otherwords the origin address you configured in cloudflare) to be able to see if your application is running, but if you are only caching static content with cloudflare and everything else is being served directly by your web application then you can simply ping your web application as per normal.